# Mysql add value to the value opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

well, im trying to get the shipping cost for each product but i have no idea to get the shipping cost correctly, example on my product_shipping_cost table

```
   product_id, shipping_cost
   1, 12
   2, 15
   etc.....
```

now i try to get single product shipping_cost using this query

```
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_shipping_cost WHERE product_id='" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    $cost = $query->row['shipping_cost'];
```

yes, i got the shipping cost perfectly! but what if i want to get two or more shipping cost? i mean sum the shipping_cost with the selected product_id so it would be 12+15=27 shipping cost, i use this with no luck..

```
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_shipping_cost WHERE product_id='" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    foreach($query->row as $shipping) {
    $cost = $shipping['shipping_cost'];
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: 12 and 15 are shipping costs for different product IDs. Why are you summing them? And why do you expect a query that has `WHERE product_id = $product_id` to return the shipping costs of both of them?

Comment: The main prolem seems to be that your `query()` method only returns one row of results. Do you have another method that returns all the results, so you can loop over them?

Comment: lets say you had 2 product on your shopping cart and both of the product had the different shipping cost, so in the shopping cart the shipping cost of the both product will be sum..

Comment: But your query doesn't allow for multiple products.

Comment: so how can i do this? my bad...

Answer (score 0):

$cost needs to be an array for it to store multiple costs unless you plan on using it in the for loop. ie..

```
$costTotal = 0;
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_shipping_cost");
foreach($query->row as $shipping) {
$costTotal += $shipping['shipping_cost'];
}
```

updated to reflect op comment.

Comment: i get and error 'Fatal error: Unsupported operand types'
anyway, what im trying to do is sum the shipping_cost with the selected product_id so it would be 12+15

Comment: i dont know what $query->row returns, but getting the sum of all products costs is simple, i'll update using your original to show it.

Comment: im sure your code are not wrong, i get if 0 + 0 = 6 and ? + ? = 7

Comment: There is no if... I'm not sure what you mean. just loop through the shipping cost for each product and add it to the totalCost using += operator.

Answer (score 0):

Add the costs in your query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(shipping_cost) total_shipping FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_shipping_cost WHERE product_id='" . (int)$product_id . "'");
$cost = $query->row['total_shipping'];
```

Comment: this do the trick but i dont want to sum all value in the column, just for specific product_id that are currently on the cart

Comment: change the `WHERE` clause to match the items in the cart. I don't know OpenCart, but I assume it provides a way for you to get a list of all the items. Turn that into `WHERE product_id IN (<list of IDs>)`.

Comment: I hope you don't need to multiply the shipping costs by the quantities, since that won't work with this query. You'll need to get each product's shipping cost separately, so you can multiply before adding it to the total.

Comment: This is way better than what i had in mind, aside from , as you pointed out, multiplying by quantity.

Comment: well, i dont need shipping cost by quantities as opencart have it by default, anyway i dont get what you mean by 'You'll need to get each product's shipping cost separately' is this really possible? or you mean i need to run query for each product to get cost?

Comment: I mean you would need to run a query that returns a row for each item, and loop over those rows (like the `foreach` you tried in your question), instead of just returning a single row with the total.

Answer (score 0):

done by using this code

```
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
        $product_id = $product['product_id'];

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT shipping_cost FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_shipping_cost WHERE product_id='" . (int)$product_id . "'");
        $total += $query->row['shipping_cost'];
        $cost = $total;
    }
```

but still will return an error if the shipping_cost for the product is not set in the database